# Drill down functionality in SAP FIORI

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I want to create 3 charts for 5 models of car. The charts data is present for National & Regionwise. Can I drill down the National data to regional data using SAP FIORI?

To get a single chart for National data for car models which can be drilled down to Region wise data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Functionality of using filter in charts. Is it possible in SAP FIORI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55862268/functionality-of-using-filter-in-charts-is-it-possible-in-sap-fiori)

Comment: This drill-down from one  chart (view) to another one should be possible.
Please have a look at the official docu for the “Ice Cream Machine”-Tutorial here: [sap.suite.ui.commons.tutorial.icecream](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.suite.ui.commons.tutorial.icecream).
The official docu for Charts might also be helpful: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#controls/filter/Chart and [Sample: Interactive Donut Charts in Flexbox](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.suite.ui.microchart.InteractiveDonutChart/sample/sap.suite.ui.microchart.sample.InteractiveDonutChart)